# ES error when trying to run multiple build commands on Vercel

Tags: next.js, vercel

I'm trying to deploy a NextJS project on Vercel, I changed the building command to also run a library, now it's like this:

```
yarn run build && yarn run email
```

But after I make this change the building returns this error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /vercel/path0/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js from /vercel/path0/node_modules/ora/index.js not supported.
```

What is the connection between my change and this error ? Because I searched and this error seen to be related to the versions of some libraries but this is something coming from Vercel himself.

Also this doens't happen localy.

Comment: `yarn dev` is meant for development, but not for production build. You should not use it on Vercel. Typically, for Next.js applications, `next build` is used for production build.

Comment: I'm sorry the command `was yarn build` I wrote wrong